# curl "Couldn't connect to server"

Tags: sockets, curl, gunicorn

Hello I am trying to test a socket activation mechanism and can't connect to the server.

curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost

> > curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Initially I had the error:

> > curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

And then I allowed the curl port, but now I can't connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure your `curl` version is big than `7.40`

```
curl --version
```

Second, ensure your socket file is exists by

```
ls -al /run/gunicorn.sock
```